# What kind of model to use on such a question?

Tags: probability

Suppose you have to pull out 3 tickets after eachother, the first one has 20% chance to be a good one, the second one has a 84% chance to be a good once, the third one has a 96% chance to be a good one

If you take out a bad one, you lose.

How can I find out when I have exactly 50% chance to win, 60% chance to win and so on ?

What kind of model do I use? I only know the binomial distribution , but only know how to apply that to 1 ticket/chance.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of a single draw, the probability of drawing a good ticket is just a weighted average over all possible outcomes, also called the *expected value*.

The outcomes are $o_{1} = 0.2$ chance success for the first ticket, $o_{2} = 0.84$ chance success for the second ticket, and $o_{3} = 0.96$ chance success for the third ticket.

Each ticket has a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ of being drawn: $p(o_{1})=p(o_{2})=p(o_{3})=\frac{1}{3}$

The expected value for this random variable $O$ is this weighted average:

$$P(success) = E(O) = o_{1}p(o_{1})+o_{2}p(o_{2})+o_{3}p(o_{3})$$

If you want to perform multiple draws and find your chances of $n$ successes, you can just use a binomial distribution $B(n,p)$ where the chance of success is $p=E(O)$.

Comment: hey, you have to pull each ticket after each other, not one has a chance of being pulled 1/3 . Thats why I am kinda confused xD

Comment: @kapparinocappucino I'm a little confused about what your question is. Are you drawing the tickets repeatedly with replacement? What do you mean by "not one has a chance of being pulled 1/3"?